# How to replace empty values with NULL in R?

Tags: r, sql-loader

I wrote functions in R how to replace invalid characters in my df content. The code is below.

```
     # Replace invalid characters in the df content
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub(",", ".", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("'", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("?", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("!", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("'", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("@", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("$", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x))
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("^$", NULL, x))
```

In some dataframes I have empty values which become 0. I want to make them NULL. The last line of code I wrote to replace empty value with NULL but not getting the result. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Unfortunately, I can't use NA. In the database it should arrive as NULL. I'm using SQL loader script written in R. It doesn't need to be gsub necessarily.

Comment: You can also replace a lot of these lines with one regex in your `gsub` call. This achieves your lines 2-8 in one go: `apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("['?!@$\\]", "", x))`.

Comment: @lina-linutina Have you found a solution around this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `NA` instead `NULL`, like this:

```
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("", NA, x))
```

Comment: NULL represents the null object in R: it is a reserved word.
NULL is often returned by expressions and functions whose values are
undefined.

NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing
value indicator. NA can be freely coerced to any other vector
type except raw. There are also constants NA_integer_,
NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic
vector types which support missing values: all of these are
reserved words in the R language.

Comment: You're right +1 ... by the way, you can just match empty string, no need to use `^$`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use NA. In the database it should arrive as NULL. I'm using SQL loader script written in R. It doesn't need to be gsub necessarily.

Comment: The SQL loader you are using will likely know that `NA` in R means `NULL` in whatever SQL engine you are using. `NA` is likely what you want, the other option being to use the string `"null"`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When it's loaded to sql server, it's not null, it's NA. We need NULL for reporting reasons because Tableau gets data from there.

Comment: NaN could be another solution: https://www.r-bloggers.com/difference-between-na-and-nan-in-r/